# OCaml expects pattern which doesn't appear anywhere during pattern matching

Tags: types, pattern-matching, ocaml

The line

```
Concat((a,b)) -> let x = regexp_to_nfa a and y = regexp_to_nfa b in match x.fs with [t] ->
```

brings up the error

```
37 |   Concat((a,b)) -> let x = regexp_to_nfa a and y = regexp_to_nfa b in match x.fs with [t] ->
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This pattern matches values of type regexp_t
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
         int list * int list
```

Why would the compiler think int list * int list needs to be matched when a, b clearly need type regexp_t for the regexp_to_nfa function to use them?

[Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528377/ocaml-compiler-expects-an-irrelevant-custom-type) question with a similar mistake suggests that the error stems from a previous expression having type int list * int list. However, if I move the Concat line to the start (before Empty_String ->), I get the error

```
33 |   Empty_String -> let x = fresh() and y = fresh() in
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This variant pattern is expected to have type int list
       The constructor Empty_String does not belong to type list
```

, which suggests that Concat((a,b)) or something in the line using it has type int list, which makes even less sense.

For reference, these are the types I'm working with and the code of the function I'm trying to debug:

```
type ('q, 's) transition = 'q * 's option * 'q
type ('q, 's) nfa_t = {
    sigma : 's list;
    qs : 'q list;
    q0 : 'q;
    fs : 'q list;
    delta : ('q, 's) transition list;
}

type regexp_t =
  | Empty_String
  | Char of char
  | Union of regexp_t * regexp_t
  | Concat of regexp_t * regexp_t
  | Star of regexp_t

let fresh =
  let cntr = ref 0 in
  fun () ->
    cntr := !cntr + 1 ;
    !cntr

let rec regexp_to_nfa (regexp: regexp_t) : (int, char) nfa_t = match regexp with
  Empty_String -> let x = fresh() and y = fresh() in 
  {sigma = []; qs = [x;y]; q0 = x; fs = [y]; delta = []}|
  Char(a) -> let x = fresh() and y = fresh() in 
  {sigma = [a]; qs = [x;y]; q0 = x; fs = [y]; delta = [(x,Some a,y)]}|
  Union((a,b)) -> let x = regexp_to_nfa a and y = regexp_to_nfa b and r = fresh() and s = fresh() in match (x.fs, y.fs) with ([t],[u]) -> 
  {sigma = Sets.union x.sigma y.sigma; qs = Sets.union (Sets.union x.qs y.qs) [r;s]; q0 = r; fs = [s]; 
  delta = Sets.union (Sets.union x.delta y.delta) [(r, None, x.q0); (r,None,y.q0); (t,None,s); (u,None,s)]}|
  Concat((a,b)) -> let x = regexp_to_nfa a and y = regexp_to_nfa b in match x.fs with [t] -> 
  {sigma = Sets.union x.sigma y.sigma; qs = Sets.union x.qs y.qs; q0 = x.q0; fs = y.fs; 
  delta = Sets.union (Sets.union x.delta y.delta) [(t,None,y.q0)]} |
  Star(a) -> let x = regexp_to_nfa a and r = fresh() and s = fresh() in match x.fs with [t] -> 
  {sigma = x.sigma; qs = Sets.union x.qs [r;s]; q0 = r; fs = [s]; 
  delta = Sets.union x.delta [(r, None, x.q0);(r,None,s);(s,None,r);(t, None, r)]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested `match`. So, the `Concat` pattern is parsed as part of the nested match.

You need to use `begin/end` or parentheses to isolate a `match` that's nested inside another `match`.

If you continue to use the nested match you also need to handle the case where `(x.fs, y.fs)` doesn't have the expected form (i.e., the case where one of the lists has a length other than 1). If you're positive they are never empty you can rewrite like this:

```
Union((a,b)) ->
    let x = regexp_to_nfa a
    and y = regexp_to_nfa b
    and r = fresh()
    and s = fresh() in
    { sigma = Sets.union x.sigma y.sigma;
      qs = Sets.union (Sets.union x.qs y.qs) [r;s];
      q0 = r;
      fs = [s]; 
      delta = Sets.union (Sets.union x.delta y.delta)
                    [(r, None, x.q0);
                     (r, None, y.q0);
                     (List.hd x.fs, None, s);
                     (List.hd y.fs, None, s)]
    }|
Concat((a,b)) -> . . .
```

(For what it's worth, you're using an extremely dense coding style. It would be better IMHO to format a little more loosely, or even to use a formatting tool to lay out the code automatically.)

Comment: Good idea about using List.hd. The recursion shall ensure x.fs, y.fs always have size exactly 1, and my original match statement tried to exploit this.

Comment: But OCaml exhaustiveness checking (which is awesome in general) won't know what you know. So you would get warnings, or would have to insert annotations (which are ugly IMHO) to turn off the warnings.